# Other way to share react ts components between projects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric-react, fluentui-react

I have been looking for a way to mostly share some code between projects specifically for SPFX and fluent ui. We found 3 main ways to do that.

1.
Creating a component library is the way that seemed least complicated cause it uses the same infrastructure and do all building without the need to configure it.

But this adds some issues, we need to built and manually link the solution locally to make it work, this will also work if we put in a repo. so this is mitigated.
The second is that implicitly this will also require the fluent ui and react. Plus having to place it inside a SPFX component library project.

2.
I saw some promise using paths in ts and this works fine while using the ts compiler. It will go to the folder that your proj is referring and build it at calling time. which is great. But it did not work in SPFX.

3.
Another way was to have a post install to sync the folders which seems easy enough but I wonder how practical this is plus how people are doing it, if they are, how.

All I wanted to figure out now is a way to take my component code and share as if they were in a folder of my src or a simple extension of the code. No need to have extra dependencies or build steps, just the code that can be used as a ts/tsx file. ex:

shared lib:

```
//assuming I have react and fluentui already installed for the project.
import button from 'fluentui';
export const fancyCustomButtom = (props) => {
    return (<Button text="Standard" />);
};
```

src project folder:

```
import {fancyCustomButtom} from 'shared-lib'
```

It is fine if it needs to build the files before we can use it but can we do it at build time or when the package is installed? also wouldn't it increase my bundle size by making both module dependent on things already available (react, fluentui)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the way Microsoft have architected the loading of bundles in SharePoint and Teams - I believe an SPFX component library is the best way to share code between different solutions, particularly if you are looking to minimise bundle size...

Imagine you have a library for something re-usable: a form, a set of standard branded components - something of that nature. You could put your shared code in repos and add references to it - either by publishing your own repo publicly or using the `npm install git+https://yourUrl` syntax; but what effectively happens there is that your code is pulled down in to `node_modules` for each project, and any referenced module code is included in your bundles. If you have two, three, four or more webparts on the same page - using those same libraries, you're multiplying how many times that code is included on the page.

If you follow [Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/library-component-tutorial) on setting up a component library project however, your `npm link` commands allow your types to be recognised in consuming projects without needing to actually include the bundled distribution code. You can deploy your library code once to the App Catalog, and if it's referenced in other solutions -- it's loaded on pages as needed: once.

I have found the development experience to be quite flaky at times, but it does work. When I run `gulp clean` on my library code, or come back to it after some time, I sometimes find that I need to run `npm link` and `npm link my-project-name` again as per the instructions in the above tutorial. Whenever you run `gulp build` on your library, you should also rebuild the project that consumes the library, either by using `gulp build / bundle` or by saving a file (if you're running `gulp serve`). This process works well for developing, and once it comes time to deploy, all you need to do is add a named reference to your library inside `package.json` and then deploy both `.sppkg` files to your App Catalog.

In terms of your last question re: bundle size - react is not actually included in the dependencies for an SPFX library project, but you will find it's available to use. When you build your library, if you take a look in the generated javascript in your `dist` folder, you will see it's listed as one of the dependencies for the webpacked content along with `react-dom` and `ControlStrings`. It's on line 1.

`office-ui-fabric-react` is included as a devDependency thanks to the `@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench` package that gets scaffolded with all SPFX projects - and if you check your library's `dist` javascript, you will see that included components are being webpacked and included in your bundle. I'm not entirely sure if when you pull this code in to your consuming project, whether webpack then tree-shakes to de-duplicate and ensures only necessary code is included: I don't know. Someone else may be able to illuminate us there or provide a more accurate explanation of what's going on... I will update this response if anyone comments to let me know.

And finally, this is more of a personal way of working, but it may be worth consideration:
When developing a library, I sometimes reference it in other projects via a local `npm install ../filepath` command.  This ensures that when I install the library as described, the consuming project installs any necessary dependencies. I'm able to tweak both projects if I need o. When it comes time to deploy, I commit my changes to both projects, deploy my library code to the App Catalog, and then `npm uninstall` the library from the consuming project and add a reference as described in the above tutorial. When I deploy projects that use my library, they just work.

I recently developed a library that uses `pnpjs`, in particular the `@pnp/sp` library that is used to talk to SharePoint. If you look at the *Getting Started* guide for that library, they expect you to pass a reference to your Application Customizer or Web Part `context` during setup, or explicitly set things up using a base URL and so forth - and of course, a library doesn't really have a page context of any sort - the whole point of this code is that it's reusable. So that poses a challenge. My solution was to do the setup in the consuming web part(s) and ensure that they pass a reference to the `sp` object (which is of type `SPRest`) to any code or components that exist in my library. My library has peerDependencies on those `pnp` libraries so that the code isn't duplicated in consuming projects. Sometimes you have to think about what your library needs to include in its bundle and what you expect consuming solutions to already have, and maybe find ways to ensure things aren't included that aren't needed.

For example, in the scenario you talk about, you may want to ensure `fluentui` or `office-ui-fabric-react` are only `devDependencies` or `peerDependencies` for your library. As long as your library and the project(s) consuming your library both use the right version(s) you shouldn't have any trouble, and you can document any pre-requisites with your library documentation. You can check which versions of these libraries are installed per the SPFX version you are currently using ie. SPFX v1.11 or v1.12 etc. Just run `npm ls <packagename>` to get a breakdown, or check your `package.json` file.

Comment: I eventually decided to have a repo with the versions of the libs we are using where we can import from a 'local' cdn. either it be a lib or reusable components. That way we still need to have a build step but we make sure that the versions are not messing with the other and we can hotfix it if needed. It does not rely on the component library but would also work correctly with it. 

There is also rush and other monorepos which can do it, but divinely overkill for this.

Thanks for the thorough answer.